# DNS errors and non-existing subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, github

When I visit anythinghere.mysite.tld I get a DNS error. However, if you observe the behaviour of anythinghere.google.com and anythinghere.example.com you'll see there's no DNS error.

Note: doesnotexist.mysite.tld, random.mysite.tld and so on don't exist; all non-existing subdomains seem to be affected. What could be the reason for getting a DNS error in this situation?

Note 2: I'm using GitHub Pages with CloudFlare.

**Update:** If I clear my browser cache the DNS error doesn't happen. I see the exact same behaviour at random.lsquo.com as I see at random.google.com. That's good as it's exactly what I want. However, when I then visit lsquo.com again and then re-visit random.lsquo.com I see the DNS error again.

Comment: With DNS problems you really need to tell us the domain names if you want effective advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because all the critical information is censored.

Comment: @Tim the domain name is lsquo.com. random.example.com or random.google.com is exactly the behaviour I'd like to see when I visit random.lsquo.com

Comment: @ceejayoz I've added the critical info (the domain name in question) in my comment above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Neither of anythinghere.google.com or anythinghere.example.com resolve, rather produce DNS errors.

Comment: Without really knowing what the goal actually is, my guess would be that it's about some browser behavior (optional?) which one way or another interacts with the **includeSubDomains** of `strict-transport-security:max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload`, largely based on that you say clearing the cache affects the behavior.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I need anythinghere.lsquo.com to behave exactly the same as anythinghere.google.com. For the subdomain at lsquo, I get a DNS error

Comment: As I said, I get a DNS error in both cases. What do you want to happen?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I get this for example.google.com http://imgur.com/a/rWLsq and this for example.lsquo.com http://imgur.com/a/XqxcN. I'd like example.lsquo.com to get the same as example.google.com.

Comment: @henrywright What I get is http://imgur.com/Hm0eoJU and http://imgur.com/ddAkxWQ

Comment: @henrywright Looks like your ISP is hijacking NXDOMAIN. Not good.

Comment: @ceejayoz why would my ISP do this for example.google.com and not for example.lsquo.com?

Comment: @henrywright The made-up Google.com subdomain has never served a security policy that'd cause your browser to ignore the hijacking. Your subdomain has, so your browser refuses to fall for it.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist thanks for the screenshots. So you see identical behaviour for example.google.com and example.lsquo.com?

Comment: @henrywright It does it for both. But your `strict-transport-security` including subdomains ensures that the browser will only do HTTPS under your domain, which their hijack nonsense can't support.

Comment: @ceejayoz apologies for the basic question but can you explain what you mean by security policy? do you mean HSTS?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist " It does it for both. But your strict-transport-security including subdomains ensures that the browser will only do HTTPS under your domain, which their hijack nonsense can't support." - Could you explain this some more to help me understand? Perhaps in an answer. I'd appreciate the info :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the behavior described in the question is not reproducible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it's normal to get a DNS error in all the mentioned examples (none of them resolve, neither `random.google.com` nor `random.lsquo.com`).

However, looking at your screenshots it's important to note that you do not in fact get a DNS error for `random.lsquo.com`, you get "Connection timed out".

It appears that your configured DNS server (probably provided by your ISP) does NXDOMAIN hijacking, where they make names that do not resolve, ie status NXDOMAIN, resolve to some page that generates revenue for them.

What changes the behavior after visiting your site is that you use HSTS and say that the policy also applies to subdomains.
Ie, **includeSubDomains** in `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload`

The browser is tricked by the NXDOMAIN hijack in your case as well, but as the servers hosting the NXDOMAIN-hijack site do not do HTTPS (and if it would, it wouldn't have a valid certificate for your domain anyway, so there would be no point even trying), the browser fails to connect.

All in all, your domain fares best out of the mentioned examples thanks to your HSTS policy. Good!

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you should have a Wildcard Record for your domain. Currently you don't have

```
*.lsquo.com.   IN   A       104.27.176.48
*.lsquo.com.   IN   A       104.27.177.48
*.lsquo.com.   IN   AAAA    2400:cb00:2048:1:0:0:681b:b030  
*.lsquo.com.   IN   AAAA    2400:cb00:2048:1:0:0:681b:b130
```

where the IP addresses match your `lsquo.com.`.

What I can't understand is why you got this working once and how you got it working with Google, that doesn't seem to have any wildcard records, either.

What's good is that you have HSTS configured and your sertificate has wildcard  `*.lsquo.com`. This means you have everything else in shape for your desired state. In many cases these would become the next problem.

Hopefully your webserver doesn't have a catch-all virtualhost, but uses redirects to a canonical hostname for your site instead.

Comment: I don't think this is what they are talking about, rather some variation on the "Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors" setting in the browser.

Comment: OP likely didn't get anything "working with Google". Looks like an ISP-injected NXDOMAIN page.

Comment: (For one thing, Google does not have any wildcard record, and if they did it wouldn't go to a Yahoo search page like in their screenshot)

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, that's probably the right interpretation! That fits with how strict-transport-security causes the NXDOMAIN hijack to break

Comment: So ISP broke how Google should behave and OP's sites HSTS header corrected ISP's bad desicion. Nice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Check out this answer for a good explanation of the issue https://serverfault.com/a/849371/217903

Comment: Håkan's answer is brilliant! I wasn't aware of the local environment and looked this merely from outside. However, I'll keep this answer because it - and especially its comments - might be helpful to others.

Comment: Yes your answer may be helpful to someone else. Thanks again for trying to help.